# Why is too slow to fetch data in Android Emulator (React Native)?

Tags: android, react-native, axios, android-emulator, fetch-api

Every one!

I have an issue while developing a new crypto wallet using React Native.
I am trying to fetch data from web server on Android Emulator.
But some fetch API response is very fast(1~2s). Some fetch API response is too slow(5 mins)

The fast fetch API in my code.(1~2 secs)

```
  let res = await fetch(
    `https://api.poloniex.com/markets/btc_usdt/price`
  );
```

The slow fetch API in my code. (5 mins)

```
 let res = await fetch(
  `https://api-eu1.tatum.io/v3/algorand/wallet`,
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'x-api-key': 'my_api_key'
    }
  }
);
```

In addtion, these two APIs all work fine in Chrome.(response is very fast)

Why these two API response has big difference with Android Emulator? And who can fix this bug?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-speed-up-android-emulator/